# JAX-WS and XSD Validation

Tags: java, web-services, xsd, wsdl

I have a wsdl that has a imported xsd, this xsd has quite a restrictions like this:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="len_type">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:pattern value='[:alnum:]{4} [\d]{2} [\d] [\d]{2}' />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

So I would thind that when I deploy this ear to glassfish via netbeans that there would be validation done on the data that is passed in, but this is not the case.  Is there any calls I need to make to ensure that the data is validated before it is passed to my @WebService object and turned into a Java object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [SchemaValidation](https://metro.java.net/2.0/guide/Schema_Validation.html) annotation.

Be forewarned, that it works only for web services of document/literal style. And be careful about schema validation, if you are using [XSD imports](http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?threadID=59708).

Comment: This site needs a rule against answers that are only a link.