# How to restrict jax-ws parser to not parse doctype to prevent xml entity injection

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am using a client which is sending an xml soaprequest to the server which includes a doctype decleration as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE test [
<!ENTITY xxe SYSTEM "///etc/SuSE-brand">
]>
```

In one of the entities I am sending &xxe; as an input as `<comments>&xxe;</comments>`. This is external entity injection. On the server side, the first time the request reaches it has been parsed and the comment field carries the text of the location  /etc/SuSe-brand .

I want to stop this doctype parsing, I have to check if there is some doctype, then parsing should be stopped. Or can anybody suggest which version of JAX-WS should be used to check xml entity injection?

Comment: have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8256536/jax-ws-request-validation-using-jaxb

Comment: hi kommaradHomer , thanks for ur reply.but i am not able to block external entity injection .I cannot block External entity injection throgh Saxparser because the first time the xml request reaches to server it does not have doctype in its header , it just bring the value of ///etc/SuSE-brand so i think that two different request are going from soapui.So please tell if any version of jax-ws could work.I have tried 2.1.7.But it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried out many things as changing the version of jaxws from 2.1.3 to 2.1.7 but it didn't block the xml entity injection.Finally i put a http filter where i could get the exact soaprequest from soapui.There i managed to moderate my changes and then send the changed soaprequest further.